# How to remove a big chunk of text from dataframe in R Studio

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning, gsub

I have a big data frame of website articles collected through an automatic scraper with two columns, "text" and "website". The problem is that I have found a big chunk of useless text present in all the articles from one of the websites I collected.

The text is always the same and says something by these lines "by clicking here you accept the use of cookies //rn If you would like to subscribe please click on the link below. //rn. By subscribing you accept our privacy policy //rn for more information click on this link"

I would like to find a way to clean all the text fields from this message but I could not manage so far.

**this is an example of my dataframe**

df

text
This is text1. By clicking here you accept the use of cookies //rn If you would like to subscribe please click on the link below. //rn. By subscribing you accept our privacy policy //rn for more information click on this link

this is text 2

this is text 3

this is text 4

**Desired outcome:**

df

text
this is text 1

this is text 2

this is text 3

this is text 4

**This is what I tried**:

`to_remove<-"By clicking here you accept the use of cookies //rn If you would like to subscribe please click on the link below. //rn. By subscribing you accept our privacy policy //rn for more information click on this link"`

`df<-gsub(to_remove, "", df$text)`

Alas, I get the following error message:
`error in (gsub(to_remove, "", df$text)): invalid regular expression`

I also tried to write down the text without slashes and other symbols but I got the same error message

Would anyone know any function that would be useful to clean my dataset from this big chunk of text?

Comment: Is this text `to_remove` always at the end of your actual text? Also you should assign the output of `gsub` to one column of `df` i.e `df$text` and not entire `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sub`/`gsub` should work but instead of copying the whole text why not remove everything that comes after `'By clicking here you'`. Those text that does not have these words would not be changed.

```
df$text <- sub('By clicking here you.*', '', df$text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried it but it deletes only that part and leaves all the rest, which is a fairly long chunk of text. Should I change some of the other parameters?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample of your data? Update your post with the output of `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I managed it using the regex  `"By clicking here you(.*)/?"` Thank you so much for your precious help!

Answer (score 2):

One bug to be aware of in your code is that

```
df<-gsub(to_remove, "", df$text)
```

Should be replaced with

```
df$text <-gsub(to_remove, "", df$text)
```

Another issue you may be running into is that you might have each row of your dataframe as a different sentence, in which case your replacement will not work. To fix this you could combine the text into a single string using

```
single_str_text = paste(df$text, collapse = ' ')
```

With this single string you can then do a regex deletion

```
gsub("By clicking here you.*for more information click on this link",
 '', 
 single_str_text)
```

Comment: Thanks this is really useful!